# ariflow dag_run not setting end_date

Tags: airflow

All dags in our airflow deployment are not setting the end_date on successful completion.

The `start_date` is correctly set as the datetime at which the task was started, but the `end_date` remains empty.

This adhoc query clearly shows the issue:

```
select * from dag_run where dag_id = 'my_dag' and state = 'success'
order by start_date desc
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in Airflow <=1.10. [There is already a fix for it](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/3990) in a testing branch.